# Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Account'. MVC 4 & using RouteConfig.CS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have 2 projects in same folder.
Main

- Project1
- Project2

#### Problem:

Multiple types were found that match the controller named **Account**. This can happen if the route that services this request `('{controller}/{action}/{id}')` does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the `MapRoute` method that takes a `namespaces` parameter.

The request for `Account` has found the following matching controllers:

> Project1.Controllers.AccountController
>
> Project2.Controllers.AccountController

I using Foundation 4.
Thanks advance

Comment: Are you having two MVC web projects, both having controllers..???

Comment: I think he means areas, but I am actually not sure. I don't dare correcting his question. At least he should be using areas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to use the version with this signature

```
public static Route MapRoute(
       this RouteCollection routes,
       string name,
       string url,
       Object defaults,
   string[] namespaces )
```

To make it work just set up two almost identical routes - one which includes the project1 for the namespaces parameter and then a second identical version but use project2 in the namespaces parameter. That said, it would generally be less confusing, to use different names if you can...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default_Project1",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    namespaces: new string[] { "Project1" } }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default_Project2",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    namespaces: new string[] { "Project2" }
);
```

Comment: You can edit your first answer instead of posting them seperately.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I copied an MVC project and renamed all the namespaces.

I tried the above solution but it did not work.

Visual Studio was still looking at the old namespace dll's even after I cleaned and rebuilt my project.

So the solution:

- Right-click solution, click 'Clean Solution'
- Manually delete everything in the /bin and /obj folders
- Build your solution

Comment: I had done this exact same thing.  I copied an MVC project, figuring it was easier to delete the stuff I didn't need than to create everything from scratch (or even copy it over piecemeal), and I was getting this error.  This fixed my problem.

Comment: Lifesaver.  Had to completely rename a solution/project/namespace and could not find anywhere it was referencing the old Namespace after manually editing all the files.  You are a scholar and a gentleman!